# Android camera does not save pictures

Tags: android, android-camera

Hey i am writing code to capture an image but my onPictureTaken method is never called...where am i going wrong??

my code is

```
btnCapture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            cam.takePicture(null, null, new TakeMyPicture());
        }
    });



   class TakeMyPicture implements PictureCallback
{

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        imagebytearray=data;            
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image Captured",5).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: Any messages of note in LogCat?

Comment: are you sure that `onClick()` is ever called?

Answer (score 0):

Taken strictly off of http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html.

Request permission to use camera

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

Take photo

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent(int actionCode) {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, actionCode);
}
```

Save photo

```
storageDir = new File(
    Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES
    ), 
    getAlbumName()
);
```

Set the file's name

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = 
        new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = JPEG_FILE_PREFIX + timeStamp + "_";
    File image = File.createTempFile(
        imageFileName, 
        JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX, 
        getAlbumDir()
    );
    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

Pass the location to camera app via Intent

```
File f = createImageFile();
takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
```

Comment: The OP is using the `Camera` class directly, not an `Intent`